# I need to design a program which output the specific day of the week given the date using vb console(VB net)

Tags: vb.net, date, if-statement

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim N, d, m, y, T As Integer

        Console.Write("Enter the date(DD): ")
        Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Write("Enter the month(MM): ")
        Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Write("Enter the year(YY): ")
        Console.ReadLine()


        N = d + 2 * m + (3 * (m + 1) / 5) + y + (y / 4) - (y / 100) + (y / 400) + 2
        T = N Mod 7 - 1
        If T = 1 Then
            Console.Write("The day is Monday")
            Console.ReadLine()
        ElseIf T = 2 Then
            Console.Write("The day is Tuesday")
            Console.ReadLine()
        ElseIf T = 3 Then
            Console.Write("The day is Wednesday")
            Console.ReadLine()
        ElseIf T = 4 Then
            Console.Write("The day is Thursday")
            Console.ReadLine()
        ElseIf T = 5 Then
            Console.Write("The day is Friday")
            Console.ReadLine()
        ElseIf T = 6 Then
            Console.Write("The day is Saturday")
            Console.ReadLine()
        ElseIf T = 7 Then
            Console.Write("The day is Sunday")
            Console.ReadLine()

        End If
    End Sub

End Module
```

Depending on the formula, i suppose that it should work but it's not. It's not giving me the right day. Maybe because we also need to calculate the leap year in it? I need simple vb net code.

Answer (score 4):

To me the formula you showed is unnecessary complex as there is a built in way to achieve what you want.

What about just:

```
Dim dt As New DateTime(2003, 5, 1)
Console.WriteLine("The day of the week for {0:d} is {1}.", dt, dt.DayOfWeek)
```